# Mongodb return empty array

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying to fetch data from db using nodejs/express 
last time i check everything was working normal , today i import bunch of json file into db , then when i try to fetch data from db it return an empty array. 
[Help Please]

here is my controller that i use to get items from db:

const Book = require('../models/Book')

```
/*
** Get all books from db
*/
exports.index = (req, res) => {
  Book.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err)
      res.send(err)
    res.json(result)
  })
}
```

and here is my db model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const schema = mongoose.Schema

// Book schema
const bookSchema = new schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  authors: [String],
  categories: [String]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
```

Comment: You can use robomongo to browse the data to ensure it exists to assist in troubleshooting.

Comment: Also a couple of things; make sure your stack supports ES6 (you're using arrow functions) and the authors/categories properties in your schema should either be an object type or an array with a mongoose doc _id reference, and you don't need to use const to declare the variables here.

Comment: Is the error object empty?

Comment: Install MongoDb atlas and view your document entries.Ensure your database contains imported records